# How to test for a polygon witn n vertices if it's nonintersecting polygon or not?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

How can you design an algorithm to know if an n-vertex polygon nonintersecting ?

On what criteria is the test going to be

Comment: Do you mean an algorithm more efficient than the following trivial algorithm: "Check each pair of non-adjacent sides if the two line segments intersect each other"?

Comment: I don't need an efficient algorithm , i just need that trivial one but i don't understand how will that works ?

Comment: To check whether two line segments intersect, find the intersection of their lines (if the two lines are parallel, then the obviously the line segments do not intersect). Then check that the intersection point lies between the endpoints of each of the two line segments. This means that $x$ of the intersection point should be between $x$'s of the endpoints and same for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the vertices are $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$. Write $(x_0,y_0)=(x_n,y_n)$ for easy for numbering. Then you should do the following:

```
for i from 1 to n-3 
for j from i+2 to n-1 
solve the system
```

$$\begin{cases} (1-t) x_{i-1} +t x_{i} = (1-s) x_{j-1} +s x_{j} \\ (1-t) y_{i-1} +t y_{i} = (1-s) y_{j-1} +s y_{j}  \end{cases} $$
(You can solve it on paper and  code the formula for its solution)

```
if 0<=t<=1 and 0<=s<=1 then return "self-intersecting"
end of for loops
return "non-self-intersecting"
```